# Backgrounding Command Prompt and Running at Login for Domain Users

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop, command-line-interface

### Intro

I have a Topaz eSignature pad that I have connected to a fat client PC to sign reports inside of a terminal session running on a remote server. I have it working so it will sign the reports on the server, but it requires a command prompt to be constantly running on the client-side.

### Problem

I am hoping to hide this command prompt and have it run at login for users logging into the domain on PCs. I would also like to be able to "refresh" the command every so often to prevent it form locking up*

### Background Info

Here is a general rundown of how this signature pad works with RDP and Citrix sessions (I will include the full PDF of instructions for those who are interested):

- install client-side sigsock.exe
- install server-side sigsock
- put .INI file (with unique username and server IP) in the user's C:\Users*usernamegoeshere*\Windows folder on the server
- run command prompt on client (runs the client sigsock.exe and tells it where to connect)
- Setup Guide for Topaz eSig Pad over RDP or Citrix Session

The command that is run in the command prompt on the client looks like this:

> c:\sigsock.exe **server IP address** *unique user name* 6

I assume this can be done via group policy, but I am new to .BATs/Scripts and GPO settings.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/quiet/ might help

Answer (score 3):

Use `start` in your batch file. The command prompt will still flash, but else it'll run in the background:

`start /min C:\sigsock.exe ...`

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility call `runhide` a sysadmin I know uses for that kind of thing.

I would probably try `psexec` and run the command. With psexec you can specify what session you want to run the command in (i.e. interactive session, console session, a *different session* so the user doesn't see the command being run, etc).